# Can't use other Meteor packages from within other Meteor packages

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-packages

I'm writing my own package and I need to rely on `dburles:mongo-collection-instances`. I know that the collection instances package will modify the `Mongo.Collection` object, but I can't see to use `Mongo.Collection.getAll()` from within my custom package.

```
var collections = Mongo.Collection.getAll(); // Doesn't work
console.log('collections', collections);
```

My `package.js`:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0.3.1');
  api.use('jquery');
  api.use('mongo');
  api.use('session');
  api.use('matb33:collection-hooks');
  api.use('dburles:mongo-collection-instances');
  api.use('accounts-base', ['client', 'server'], {weak: true});
...
});
```

Comment: Your package code most likely runs before any of the collections are created. You can try to run it on `Meteor.startup`, but whether or not is succeeds depends on when the code that creates the collections runs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you structured your package? I haven't used dburles collection instances but here is a proper way of structure:

```
/packagefolder
 both.js
 package.js
```

In your `package.js`

```
Package.describe({
summary: 'mycollection collection',
  name: 'mycollection:mycollection',
  version: '0.0.1'
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.use('jquery');
  api.use('mongo');
  api.use('session');
  api.use('matb33:collection-hooks');
  api.use('dburles:mongo-collection-instances');
  api.use('accounts-base', ['client', 'server'], {weak: true});

  api.addFiles([
    'both.js'
  ], ['server', 'client']);

  api.export('MyCollection');
});
```

I recommend aldeed collection package.. here's a `both.js` demo

```
MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');

Schemas = {};
Schemas.MyCollection = new SimpleSchema({
  profileId: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date
  }
});

MyCollection.attachSchema(Schemas.MyCollection);
```